# How to check if every strings from set contains each string from list?

Tags: python

I have got a list of titles in list and set of strings. I want to check whether each of titles from list is in any string in set. The code is working fine if string from list is exactly the same as string in set but I would like to make this working if string in set "contains" string from list. Here is my code:

```
for link in deduplicated_list:
    rdeep = requests.get(link)
    soup_deep = BeautifulSoup(rdeep.text, 'html.parser')
    if any(ele in str(soup_deep.title) for ele in list_of_books):
        print(soup_deep.title)
```

Comment: can you provide examples? such as your list and your set?

Comment: I have a list of books so it's set of strings like "<title>Peace and War for really good price only $5</titile>"  and I have list of books like "Peace and War" so i want to check if Peace and War and like 50 more titles is in any place at the first, second third... etc element in set and if it's I want to print that for now

Comment: so you want to check if the title is an element in the list? can't you just do a for loop and check if element in some_list ?

Comment: I did so and that's work but I would like to check whether element is part of longer string (not exactly the same)

Comment: then for every element in the list, check if the string you are checking is in that element, basically a substring

Comment: please provide an input and wanted output

Comment: list1 = ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
set2 = ["Book of cats", "Book of elephants", "Book of ants"]

I would like to check every element in list1 if it's in any element in set2 so in this case for cat would be true, for dog false and for bird also false

Comment: have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["cat", "dog", "bird"] 
set2 = ["Book of cats", "Book of elephants", "Book of ants"]

for animal in list1:
    for book in set2:
        if animal in book:
            print(f"FOUND, {animal} in '{book}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

A **Pythonic** way to do this would be to **chain** the **for loops**.

```
myset = {"cat meow", "dog ruff", "bird chirp"}

mylist1 = ["cat", "dog"]
mylist2 = ["run", "fun"]

any(animal in animal_sound for animal in mylist1 for animal_sound in myset)
any(animal in animal_sound for animal in mylist2 for animal_sound in myset)
```

**Output:**

```
True False
```